# Implement didSelect in a collection view inside a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying to perform a segue from a collection view which is inside a table view cell, the view looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiqRI.png)

To explain it well,  I have a table view, each row has a cell , inside the second row , I have a collection view which includes several products

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemTitle", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    case 3:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SectionTitle", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    case 4:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Inside my ItemCell class I have the following

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "singleItemCell", for: indexPath) as! singleItemCell

    cell.itemImage.image = images[indexPath.row]
    cell.itemImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


    return cell
}
```

I want to perform a segue such as when the user select a cell from the collection view, It takes him to another view controller. How can I do that ?

I tried performSegue but it does not allow me since I am in the cell class

Please any tips ?

Comment: use a delegate pattern to tell the tableViewController to perform the segue

Comment: You can only perform segue from a ViewController (to another one). That's why you can't do it "inside your cell". You already used delegate: `UITableView`, `UICollectionView`. So do the same, add a custom delegate to your `CollectionCell`, to tell your ViewController when a collectionviewcell is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your ItemCell class make a variable for referencing your ViewController like this:

```
var productVC:UIVIewController?
```

while loading TableView Cell set the reference to self like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.productVC = self
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

then implement the didSelect UICollectionView delegate method in ItemCell Class

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   productVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pass your segue identifier here..", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
 protocol ProductCellDelegate: class {
       func didChoosedProduct(item: ItemImage)
    }

     class ProductCell {

            @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

            // Your Model Array
            var itemImages: [ItemImages] = [] {
                didSet { 
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
             } 
            // Must set the delegate to your viewcontroller object in tableviewcell cell for rowat indexpath method
            weak var delegate: ProductCellDelegate?

            override func awakeFromNib() {
                  self.collectionView.delegate = self
              }
        }

    extension ProductCell: UICollectionViewDelegate {

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = self.itemImages[indexPath.row]
        self.delegate?.didChoosedProduct(item: selectedItem)
    }
  }
```

Implement `ProductCellDelegate` in your viewcontroller. Call performsegue to navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` not in tableView cell, but in your `ViewController`. 
You can access to collectionView in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, so you can assign it `dataSource` and `delegate` to `self`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    case 1:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemTitle", for: indexPath) as? ItemCell {
            cell.collectionView?.delegate = self
            cell.collectionView?.dataSource = self
            return cell
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

And from `ViewController` you can make `performSegue` method